# How to iterate over series?

Tags: python, regex, function

I have 'leads_r' data frame, which has 'links' column. This column includes either URLs or NaN values. What I am supposed to do is iterate over this column and if it has URLs then get the domain of this URL. Here is my code, which didn't work:

```
def domains(series):
    for url in series:
        if url!=np.NaN:
            url=re.findall(r'://([\w\-\.]+)', URL)

leads_r['links'].apply(domains)
```

The error I got is:  ''float' object is not iterable

The dataset example:

| name | links | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lisa | https://example.com | insta |
| John | https://abcdf.sales.ar | NaN |
| Tom | NaN | facebook |
| Vika | https://another/smth/page#2 | email |

How I want it to look like:

| name | links | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lisa | example | insta |
| John | abcdf | NaN |
| Tom | NaN | facebook |
| Vika | another | email |

This option isn't working either:

```
def domains(url):
    if url!=np.NaN or url is not None:
       url=re.findall(r'://([\w\-\.]+)', url)
       return url
```

leads_r['links'].apply(domains)

It returns Error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMfrR.png)

Comment: Please post an actual example (simple input and expected output). How can we know how your data frame looks like exactly if you don't show it to us? Please be more specific and provide more details

Comment: Here is dataset model and model expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Series.str.extract` directly:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

leads_r=pd.DataFrame({'name':['Lisa', 'John','Tom','Vika'], 'links':['https://example.com', 'https://abcdf.sales.ar', np.nan, 'https://another/smth/page#2'], 'source':['insta', np.nan,'facebook','email']})
leads_r['links'] = leads_r['links'].str.extract(r'://([^/.]+)', expand=False)
```

Output:

```py
>>> print(leads_r.to_string())
   name    links    source
0  Lisa  example     insta
1  John    abcdf       NaN
2   Tom      NaN  facebook
3  Vika  another     email
```

The `://([^/.]+)` regex matches a `://` substring and then captures any one or more chars other than `/` and `.` chars into Group 1. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sSIR54/1).